# Remote server returned an error (403 Forbidden)

Tags: visual-studio, azure-storage, message-queue

I have a remote team that is on the other side of the world accessing our systems via VPN and then into a remote desktop session via citrix to connect to the visual studio environment.  Our website uses Azure message queue and Azure storage accounts to keep those messages as they communicate with our data warehouse this all works great when we publish the code and run from our staging environment.

However when our off shore team is running the site locally to perform there testing they constantly get a 403 error when trying to send messages to the message queue.

[image]

I thought it had to do with the citrix profiles and the time difference between where they ran the code and the azure systems so we had our help desk modify the profiles so that citrix would not use the time zone of the developer but that didn't work.

Any help would be great

---

Here is the snippet where the error occurs:

```
public class AzureMessageQueue : IMessageQueue
{
    private readonly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.QueueCloudQueue queue;

    public AzureMessageQueue(string connectionString, string queueName, int retrySeconds = 60, int messageBatchSize = 30)
    {
        queue = CloudStorageAccount
            .Parse(connectionString)
            .CreateCloudQueueClient()
            .GetQueueReference(queueName);

        queue.CreateIfNotExists();

        //...

    }

    //...
}
```

Stack trace:

```
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.Exists(Boolean primaryOnly, QueueRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)    
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.CreateIfNotExists(QueueRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
at [MyCompany].AzureMessageQueue..ctor(String connectionString, String queueName, Int32 retrySeconds, Int32 messageBatchSize)
...
```

The connection string used is in this form:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[account name];AccountKey=[account key]
```

I verified that the key is still active, and this connection string works when the application is executed elsewhere.

Comment: The 403 error is usually an authentication issue. Can you provide some information on how your code is authenticating access to the queue?

Comment: Thanks for responding @TamraMyers-Microsoft.  I've updated the post above with a code block and stack trace.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: The 403 error is happening on the call to create the queue. In your code, that is the first code that contacts the service. I'm guessing that is the first call to Azure Storage in your application, is that correct? If so, that suggests that there is a problem with the connection string. I know that you said that it works elsewhere.

Comment: Can you ask them to connect to the account from a tool like Azure Storage Explorer (http://storageexplorer.com/)? Then ask them to create a queue using the tool.